# Why can't I get all the values from my generator?

Tags: python-3.x

```
args = (i for i in ["A", "B", "C", "A"])
for x in ["C", "B", "A"]:
    kw = [i for i in args if i == x]
    for j in kw:
        print(j)
```

When I run this script, only got "C" in result.
How do i get all elements?

Comment: What is the point of the first line?

Comment: This question should be reworded or given a new title to reflect what it is actually about. The selected answer has nothing to do with generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since args is an iterator, once you iterate through it (which you do in the third line), you cannot iterate through it once again. What I suggest you do is to convert args to a list or a tuple. So, instead of this:

```
args = (i for i in ["A", "B", "C", "A"])
```

do either of these:

List:

```
args = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]
```

Tuple:

```
args = ("A", "B", "C", "A")
```

Comment: You are correct. List and tuple comprehension is not required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just wondered why generator doesn't work.

Comment: Generators won't work because you can only iterate through generators once. Once you have iterated though all of its contents, it will become empty.

Answer (score 1):

**Try just This**:

```
args = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]
```

Because you're doing a generator, which is why it doesn't work, so just directly do the list.

**Whole Code:**

```
args = ["A", "B", "C", "A"]
for x in ["C", "B", "A"]:
    kw = [i for i in args if i == x]
    for j in kw:
        print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
C
B
A
A
```

#### Explanation:

When you iterate trough an generator it is gonna get empty, like do `next` to it it will be similar to `list.pop(0)`, generator s same as yield in a def (function)

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
args = (i for i in ["A", "B", "C", "A"])  
x = ["C", "B", "A"]: 
kw = [i for i in args if i in x]  

for j in kw: print(j)
```